How to call a function multiple times in openmp
I have a piece of OpenMP code to call a function multiple times. I want to open as many threads as number of functional callings:
void multiple_func_calling ()
{
    int x[6]{0,1,2,3,4,5};
   
    double y[60000]();
   
    omp_set_num_threads(6); 

    #pragma omp parallel
    #pragma omp for
    for(int i=0; i<6; ++i)
    {
        A(x[i], y)
    }
}

void A(const int& xi, double *y)
{
    int count{0};

    for(int i=0; i<100; ++i)
        for(int j=0; j<100; ++j)
        {
            y[count+10000*xi]=xi*10.0;
            count++; 
        }
}

Here, does each thread i make one corresponding call of function A(x[i], y). What happened if the number of threads  is larger than 6. How does the for-loop for(int i=0; i<6; ++i) will be distributed among more than 6 threads?
As I understand, the two-for-loops inside each call of A(x[i], y) are not parallelized with OpenMP without using collapse.
Is there a way to parallelize these two inner-for-loops as well? But it may cause a issue for incremental of count in the inner-for-loops if we parallelize this part as well. How to avoid this wrong incremental of the variable count?
Or is it better to leave inside two for-loops serial?

Nothing special happen if there is more thread. For exemple, with 8 threads, the 6 first will execute the loop and the 2 others will not execute it. Threads may actively wait for new incoming work but you can control if they wait passively or actively with OMP_WAIT_POLICY (impacting the latency and the CPU load). Note you can specify num_threads in the parallel loop. Spawning a variable number of threads can make things slower if the threads do not last for a while (as stated in your previous question where people told you to avoid that).

If there is less threads than the number of item computed in the loop, then the scheduling is dependent of the schedule clause if any (or the implicit default schedule value which is AFAIK auto -- so static in practice). The static scheduling without special parameter will use a round robin scheduling. You can see that in the OpenMP documentation (please read it). You can also find previous posts about this.

No, indeed, the inner code of A will not be parallelized by OpenMP. You can spawn tasks in it if you want to use more thread that the outer loop can. In the current code, you cannot parallelize things more as long as the omp_set_num_threads is called. This is one reason why you should not set threads manually. Also, if the number of iteration of the outer loop is much bigger than the number of (possibly logical) cores, then it will cause a massive performance drop due to thread over-subscription. Tasks are the way to go for that.

I think It is better not to parallelize A. 100*100=10_000 iterations is not so much and creating threads takes a long time (at least several µs). Note that the loop in A cannot be parallelized without modifying it since count is sequentially increased in it. Also please note that j is unused so the j-loop is useless. It has a strong impact on performance since compilers can remove it with optimizations. It can also impact answers (since 100 iterations is so small that parallelizing all of that is certainly a bad idea).

Thank you paleonix for editing my questions, and thank you Jérôme Richard for very detailed explanations to my questions.  This is really really a great help for me.
